# Dynamically load a drop down on selecting an option from another drop down

Tags: javascript, django

I am working on a web application over Django 1.4.5 framework. I want to populate the options in a drop down list(select id="packages") dynamically depending on the option selected in another drop down list(select id="ida"). I have looked out for answers but nothing is pointing in the right direction. here is my code:

**My template (html):**

```
function getPackages(elementId)
{
//This is what I want to write, but could not figure out.
}

Select IDA's: 
<select id="ida" name="ida" onchange="getPackages('ida');">
{% for ida in ida_list %}
<option value="ida{{ ida.id }}">{{ ida.ida_display_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

Select packages to install: <select id="package" name="package"multiple="multiple" size="5">
{% for package in package_list %}
<option value="package {{ package.pkg_id }}">{{ package.display_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

**My view:**

```
def automation(request):
    ida_list = IDA.objects.all()
    ida = IDA.objects.get(ida_name='VSA')   #this is what I want to do from javascript
    package_list = ida.package_set.all()
    context = {'ida_list' : ida_list, 'package_list' : package_list}
    return render_to_response('vsawebauto/automation.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**My models:**

```
class IDA(models.Model):
    ida_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ida_display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ida_name    

class Package(models.Model):
    pkg_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    pkg_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="NULL")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="NULL")    
    IDAs = models.ManyToManyField(IDA)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.display_name
```

**Brief explanation:** Depending on the IDA selection on html page, i want the packages to be displayed in the drop down list dynamically. Packages can belong to multiple IDAs  and vice versa(many-many relationship in models classes). So, I want that as soon as user selects an IDA, the javascript should get the object corresponding to that IDA (something like: ida = IDA.objects.get(ida_name='VSA')) and the packages should be fetched for that IDA and displayed.

Comment: What problems are you running into?  Where is the code for getPackages

Comment: I could not figure out a way to do that. Sorry, I should have mentioned that before. I can get the packages for a specific IDA (eg. VSA as shown in above view) by using 'ida.package_set.all()' and display the package_list on the template. But I want to do the same thing in javascript (to display the packages corresponding to a selected IDA in the list) @Nix

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made it some time.

in some urls.py

```
#...
url(r'^package_ajax/$', PackageForIdaView.as_view(), name="ida_change_all"),
url(r'^package_ajax/(?P<pk>[-_\w]+)/$', PackageForIdaView.as_view()),
#...
```

in some views.py

```
class PackageForIdaView(ListView):
    template_name = "partial/package_options.html"
    model = Package
    context_object_name = "package_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = super(PackageForIdaView, self).get_queryset()
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            query_set = query_set.filter(IDAs=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return query_set
```

in some javascript:

```
$('#ida').change(function(event){
    var url = "{% url "ida_change_all" %}";
    var ida_id = this.value;
    if ida_id != undefined:
        url += ida_id
    $('#package').load(url);
})
```

in "package_options.html" template:

```
{% for package in package_list %}
    <option value="package {{ package.pkg_id }}">{{ package.display_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Maybe somethings fails,i don't remember all details, but that is the way.

Hope this helps!